# How can I make my home web server acessible on port 80 or 443?

Tags: webserver, port, http, nginx

I'm trying to use an old laptop as a web server for testing purposes, so bought I a domain on godaddy, and was expecting to be able to point the domain to my server on the default port 80 so I could just send to others as "mydomain.com", instead of "mydomain.com:1234" or some other random ports. I'm being successful on hosting it on other non-reserved ports, like the 1234 on my example, but ports 80 and 443 just won't work. (Even port 22 works when I SSH into the server).

I already tried port forwarding port 80, turning on DMZ, allowing port 80 on the router firewall, making the port forwarding listen to 80(external) and pass it to 1234(local), and he firewall on the server is already set up to allow port 80.

My idea is to host this server entirely at my own home, without resorting to AWS, Google Cloud and etc. If there is a way to do this all without third party websites, I'd prefer it, but if there is a free method using online tools, feel free to suggest them as well!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your ISP blocking ports 80 and 443? Many ISPs do this for home connections...

Comment: Can you check if port 80 is already in use by another application? In Windows open a command prompt (cmd) and run: `netstat -ano | findstr /C:":80 "`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your router firmware is crap. I assume it is running web services on port 80 and 443 and the firmware is badly written to support these rather then forward them.

Try a different router firmware like dd-wrt if that's an option, or use a different router.

Its not free, but a VPN with a static IP address would be another workaround.

Comment: I do have another router that I could plug to the ISP's router+modem that I'm currently using and see is I have more luck. If this isn't really the ISP blocking the ports, it could work. Thanks for the tip! Gotta try that tomorrow